# Toggling a populated list view between visible and invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation, android-togglebutton

I have created a simple list view with two different text views (shown below). I want to have a series of rows that will display more information when clicked--one text view hidden that can be toggled by clicking the other text view. I think my problem might be the linear layout encapsulating the two text views, but I'm not sure. The slide_up and slide_down animations were basic ones taken from a website.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="toggle_contents"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="example"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The list view is populated from a content provider as follows:

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   //  listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    ListView mylist=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    do{
        String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
       // String name_str = id +" : "+ name;
        listItems2.add(id);
        listItems.add(name);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }while(!cursor.isAfterLast());

    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, listItems2, listItems);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to toggle between visible and invisible with the slide up and slide down animations:

```
public void toggleContents(View v){
        if(txt_hidden.isShown()){
            slide_up(this, txt_hidden);
            txt_hidden.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            txt_hidden.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            slide_down(this, txt_hidden);
        }
        //txt_hidden.setVisibility(txt_hidden.isShown()? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public static void slide_down(Context ctx, View v){

        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_down);
        if(a != null){
            a.reset();
            if(v != null){
                v.clearAnimation();
                v.startAnimation(a);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void slide_up(Context ctx, View v){

        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_up);
        if(a != null){
            a.reset();
            if(v != null){
                v.clearAnimation();
                v.startAnimation(a);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set the `txt_hidden` variable? I believe it might be pointing to a view that is different than the one you are actually trying to change the visibility for.

I would suggest that you don't set the click listener in the xml file, but rather in getView() of your adapter when you are building your list item view:

```
private class ViewHolder
{
    TextView mTextView1;
    TextView mTextView2
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_1, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.mTextView1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        viewHolder.mTextView2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        viewHolder.mTextView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do your animation here
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.mTextView1.setText(mElements1.get(position));
    viewHolder.mTextView2.setText(mElements2.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add tag to the view that you set OnClickListener() to, for using animations on another view

```
...
view.setOnClickListener(this);
view.setTag(textViewToShowOnClick);
...

public void onClick(View v){
    ...
    TexView textViewToShowOnClick = (TextView) v.getTag();
    v.slideUp(...);
    ...
}
```